# Automorphisms and Finite Cyclic Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

The Question:
Let C be a finite cylic group and let $ E \subset C $ be a subgroup of C. Prove that every automorphism $\alpha: C\rightarrow C$ we have $\alpha(E) = E$.

I know that every subgroup of a cylic group is cylic, and that for any $e \in E$ that the $o(e) = o(\alpha (e))$ but how can I connect these ideas. Hints would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Well,  if you want a hint, how many different subgroups of order $m$ are there in a cyclic group of order $n$?

Comment: @MattSamuel. If m divides n then there is one?

Comment: Key word is *one*.

Comment: @MattSamuel is it true that in a cyclic group of order N that the order of all its elements is unique.

Comment: No, that's not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $E\leq C$ is a subgroup of a finite cyclic group $C$, so $E=\langle g\rangle$ for some $g\in G$. If $\alpha\in\mathrm{Aut}(C)$, then $|\alpha(g)|=|g|$, so $\alpha(E)=\langle \alpha(g)\rangle$ and
$$|E|=|g|=|\alpha(g)|=|\alpha(E)|$$
As $C$ has at most one subgroup of a given order, it follows that $E=\alpha(E)$.